# WPF Textwrapping doesnt work in items control

Tags: c#, wpf

Somehow textwrap doesn't work.

I'm new to WPF so if anyone has an idea why this doesn't work, I would be thankful.

Here's my code:

```
                <ItemsControl Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding VRCItemsPaged}">
                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="310"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="351"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Label}" Grid.Column="0" Text="Description"/>
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Label}" Grid.Column="1" Text="Code"/>
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Label}" Grid.Column="2" Text="Value"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="Auto">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="280"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="351"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox FontWeight="Normal" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                                <TextBox FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=Code}"/>
                                <TextBox FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Column="4" IsEnabled="False"    Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is more of another question than an answer but I needed to include a screen shot, that's why it's not a comment.

What about your question isn't actually working? I've just created a simple test window using your ItemsControl XAML and I'm seeing text wrapping properly.

[image]

The XAML I used is

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ItemsControl Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="310"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="351"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Description"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Code"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Value"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="Auto">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="280"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="351"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox FontWeight="Normal" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                    <TextBox FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=Code}"/>
                    <TextBox FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Column="4" IsEnabled="False"    Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

And the code behind is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public ObservableCollection<TestObject> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<TestObject>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Items.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<TestObject>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));



        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<TestObject>();
            Items.Add(new TestObject() { Description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." });
            Items.Add(new TestObject() { Description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." });
        }
    }

    public class TestObject : DependencyObject
    {


        public string Description
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Description.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), typeof(TestObject), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    }
}
```

Comment: Found the solution. I defined a style of isEnabled=false, where i set the height. When height auto, it works.
Thanks anyway